# why text is not matched in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write `test case` of `functional component` .
I just write if there is required field it will show `required text`.but my test is not passed why

```
it("get text of required field", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({
      error: {
        olmIdError: true
      }
    });
    console.log(wrapper.find(FormHelperText).text());
    expect(wrapper.find(FormHelperText).text()).toEqual("Required..!!");
  });
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/43k6lw60x

**component**

```
 <Input
            error={error.olmIdError || apiError}
            id="olm-id"
            type="text"
            value={olmId}
            classes={{
              root: classes.inputRoot,
              focused: classes.focusedLabel,
              underline: classes.underlineInput
            }}
            placeholder="Enter OLM ID"
            onChange={handleChange("olmId")}
          />
          {error.olmIdError ? (
            <FormHelperText error={error.olmIdError} id="weight-helper-text">
              {MESSAGES.REQUIRED}
            </FormHelperText>
          ) : null}
```

**getting error**

```
Expected value to equal:
  "Required..!!"
Received:
  "<WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(FormHelperText)) />"

  44 |       }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The test passes if you change the assertion to

`expect(wrapper.find(FormHelperText).children().text()).toEqual("Required..!!");`

Here is the [Codesandbox working](https://codesandbox.io/s/00pw6x6y2n).

[.text()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html#text--string) returns the rendered text of the current tree. Output is a little weird because the current tree is `FormHelperText` shallow rendered. Calling `.children()` first results in the tree just being the `Required..!!` text.